# Table - align according decimal comma

Tags: tables

How can I align numbers in table according to the decimal comma please when I don't know how many numbers are befor the comma and how many decimal places the number will have?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bm}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{icomma,dcolumn,booktabs}

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{8}{c} @{}}
\toprule
Číslo & $P$ & $T_0$ & $e$ & $\omega$ & $i$ & $a$  \\[0.33ex]
zdroje& (dny) & (RJD) & & ($^\circ$) & ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) \\
\midrule
1 & 5,732436(15) & 54002,780(46) & 0,0910(37) & 149,2(3,0) &  &  \\
2 & 5.732824(3) & 54002,7241(96) & 0,0858(41) & 145,6(3,9) && \\
3 & 5.732824(1) & 54002,7775(34) & 0,0883(26) & 149,1(2,3) && \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please describe a case where you have a table with numbers of which you don't know 'how many numbers are before the comma and how many decimal places the number will have'? In the example code in your question, you could just count.

Comment: Do you know of `siunitx` package?

Comment: I mean that not all number will have same format - same count before and after decimal comma. So it should be set according to the greatest? I know about siunitx package but it doesn't work because I do not have an update and I don't know how it update - I can not find MikTex Console in my computer.

Comment: it seems that you have an old MikTeX installation ... for upgrade use upgrade utility or better console. for instruction see MikTeX home page. number of digits you need to accommodate to the number with biggest number of digits in each column separately (as i did in my answer)

Comment: I don't know how to update it https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461728/miktex-update-packages?noredirect=1#comment1161261_461728

Answer (score 2):

with `siunitx` and `makecell` packages:

[image]

in your mwe you have mess in use of decimal points and commas. i decide to use decimal points. if you like to have commas in resulting table, than you need to add in preamble:

```
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
```

also your use of uncertainty (with commas) is not clear. such notation is not supported  in the  `siunitx` pacakage (as far as i know).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                            c
                            S[table-format=1.6(2)]
                            S[table-format=5.3(2)]
                            S[table-format=1.4(2)]
                            S[table-format=3.1(2)]
                            cc % for those columns is not clear what is in them
                            }
    \toprule
\makecell[t]{Číslo\\ zdroje}
    &   {\makecell[t]{$P$\\ (dny)}}
        &   {\makecell[t]{$T_0$\\ (RJD)}}
            &   {\makecell[t]{$e$}}
                &   {\makecell[t]{$\omega$\\ (\si{\degree})}}
                    &   {\makecell[t]{$i$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}
                        &   {\makecell[t]{$a$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}    \\
    \midrule
1 & 5.732436(15) & 54002.780(46)  & 0.0910(37) & 149.2(30) &   &            \\
2 & 5.732824(3)  & 54002.7241(96) & 0.0858(41) & 145.6(39) &   &            \\
3 & 5.732824(1)  & 54002.7775(34) & 0.0883(26) & 149.1(23) &   &            \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Since the OP uses commas rather than dots as the decimal separator, I'd addt the option `output-decimal-marker={,}`.

Comment: @Mico, i sow that she has mess in using decimal dots and commas. also i'm confusing in use of comas in uncertainty. but this over latex issue :-). i will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much and `S[table-format=1.6(2)]` belongs to siunitx package?

Comment: @Elisabeth, yes, it is. for more details you need to read its documentation. it is very educational. beside latex topic it is also informative about SI units.  `S[table-format=1.6(2)]` means that column is centered at decimal point, has reserved place for 1 integer digit and 6 decimal, to which follows 2 digits for uncertainty.

Comment: I have a problem with this package (I added picture in my question). I have it installed, but there is a problem.

Comment: @Elisabeth, sorry, but my crystal ball is out of order, so i can't see, what is your problem :-(. If you have installed it, than try to test my answer as it is. it works. if you receive errors, than please tell us, what errors are. the best in new question about use of `siunitx` .

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R932z.png

Comment: Is please an alternative to `S[table-format=1.6(2)]`?