# MikTeX update packages

Tags: miktex, updating

How to update MikTeX please? In the second picture I tried this opportunity and the update not succed. I read that admin update help, but I cannot it open. I have nothing ticked and select all is grey. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your version of `MikTeX` and what is your operating system?

Comment: I have Windows 7 and  2.7s version of MikTeX

Comment: Your miktex looks quite outdated. You can try to update first with update admin, but such large update jumps are often quite difficult.

Comment: I cannot open admin update. There is a error in the first picture

Comment: I would uninstall the old version and reinstall a fresh version.

Comment: So I should uninstal MikTex? I found out I have version 2.9.
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOR57.png

Comment: There are several versions 2.9 which one do you have? https://miktex.org/news

Comment: To answer a specific person, you must precede their nickname with the symbol `@`, read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 4):

Updating older versions of MiKTeX is problematic you can attempt it however see the following comment.

Note what is written on the MiKTeX 2.8 Status Page:

> This version has reached the ‘end-of-life’ status. It will not be
>   possible to install packages from the remote package repository. The
>   current release is 2.9.

The main reason for API 87 error is there is an open file blocking the install.
This could be another application or two instances of MiKTeX app or even a stuck part from previous running compilation.

If you are confident about "killing" windows tasks, you could try to remove them. Otherwise you need to use **Windows 7 Start button** to "reboot" i.e. Shut down then restart

However in **Windows 10 it may be better to "Restart" Windows** *(NOT Shut down)*

When you restart avoid using any related commands *(exit/close any adobe background task or other pdf handler app)*. Close any editor e.g. TeXworks and **do not run any command line tex compilation** as many users have found simply running pdfLaTeX can initiate the file locking and that is what can be causing open files to block MiKTeX updating them.

Run MiKTeX console *(IF you have dual install use admin first)* under "Tasks" Refresh the filename database and try selecting updates again.

The console is usually seen in the Icon tray as a small blue circle or a shortcut from installation, you should be able to run it from a command prompt by typing `> miktex-console`
If you can't then your install may be out of date or is not correct as it should be on your system path. To check from command prompt run> `mpm --print-package-info=miktex-console-bin-2.9` there should be three run-time files listed, if not try> `mpm --install=miktex-console-bin-2.9`

Some users have found closing MiKTeX console **fully** and re-entering triggers the update process. Other command line sequences that may help are

```
initexmf --update-fndb
initexmf --mkmaps  
initexmf --mklinks --force  
mpm --find-updates  
mpm --update
```

If you have dual *(admin and basic user)* then you may need to add `--admin` after `initexmf` and `mpm` with the commands above like this `mpm --admin --update`

If console is working but updates are not the final suggestion is

1. Start MiKTeX console
2. Click Cleanup to navigate to the cleanup page.
3. Click **Reset the MiKTeX installation to factory defaults**
4. In "Tasks" refresh the filename database and the font map files

Comment: You mean this? https://wintip.cz/585-jak-provest-cisty-restart-windows

Comment: So I should open cmd and write "DO Shut down and restart"?

Comment: Sorry no simply use the normal end of day close and switch on

Comment: I hhut down the computer and switch on, but the error is still there.

Comment: when you started computer what sequence of commands did you use, what I am trying to understand is do you have an editor or compilation (pdfLaTeX) running ? it must only be one MiKTeX **update** not a competing command

Comment: I have compilation (pdfLaTeX) running. What about I uninstall MikTeX and install TexLive?

Comment: Many people run MiKTeX with occasional problems, but it can be sometimes be frustrating especially if there are user application conflicts. I use MiKTeX **portable** because I find that easier. Tex Live is Large to download but you usually have less problems with updates. If you do want to change **first try** the following. In MiKTeX console bottom left there is an option to reset to factory condition before uninstall. Try that reset first, it may clear your issue. then if you have no success use the uninstall option and make your choice as to which TeX engine you wish to try next.

Comment: I have no Console, only the porograms in the first picture in my question. Which do you mean?

Comment: [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuQEJ.png I can't find a console.

Comment: @KJO To answer a specific person, you must precede their nickname with the symbol @, read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: @AndréC I was working on the premise the author of the post will always be notified of any new comment. You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and the author have commented on the post so far, the @ name will be automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value.

Comment: Elisabeth I have to admit it seems your installation from more than a year ago is difficult to update as most recent commands are not working. I have to suggest you take this issue to the MiKTeX site or uninstall / reinstall a new single user basic version